# Server error when writing or reading files

Tags: php, apache, file

I develop the following code:

```
if (time() - filemtime('current.txt') > 5)
{
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://live.liveradio.ir:8000/liveradiomp3_48.xspf");
    foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    {
        if ($child->getName() == 'trackList')
        {
            foreach($child as $child2)
            {
                if ($child2->getName() == 'track')
                {
                    foreach($child2 as $child3)
                    {
                        if ($child3->getName() == 'title')
                        {
                            $fp = fopen('current.txt', 'w');
                            fwrite($fp, json_encode(array('data',$child3)));
                            fclose($fp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo (file_get_contents('current.txt'));
```

but when I run it the following page shown:

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://liveradio.ir/temp.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

the permission of `temp.php` and `current.txt` are 777. When I comment the following line, the problem solved.

```
$fp = fopen('current.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode(array('data',$child3)));
fclose($fp);
echo (file_get_contents('current.txt'));
```

Where is the problem? This code works correctly on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The url is offline. That's your main problem ;)

Comment: I just checked again. It's offline. ;) Maybe it's just useable within Ireland or something like that. You have this in your error message: `http://liveradio.ir/temp.php` but it's not in your code, so it seems to be a maintenance page or something like this. Idea: Maybe it's just reachable via special "user agents", like streaming software, but not for browsers, php scripts etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check that fetching XML over this special port 8000 is allowed in the remote server configuration.